# R8: Type com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeAccessibilityManagerSpec is defined multiple times

Tags: react-native, apk, gradlew

> ERROR:C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\transforms-3\24d11a768227ded42c3db1fd43c69ff3\transformed\jetified-react-native-0.70.5-release-runtime.jar: R8: Type com.facebook.fbreact.specs.NativeAccessibilityManagerSpec is defined multiple times: C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\transforms-3\24d11a768227ded42c3db1fd43c69ff3\transformed\jetified-react-native-0.70.5-release-runtime.jar:com/facebook/fbreact/specs/NativeAccessibilityManagerSpec.class, C:\Users\user\ReactNative\Nasso\android\app\build\intermediates\javac\release\classes\com\facebook\fbreact\specs\NativeAccessibilityManagerSpec.class

j'ai supprimé le cache et le dossier build
ensuite ./gradlew clean
./gradlew build

si j'execute ./gradlew ensembleDebug ca marche
si 'exécute ./gradlew ensembleRelease j'obtien l'erreur .

que puise faire !

Comment: English only in here please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions have to be written in English.

Comment: I try build react-native  release apk .

Comment: I try build react-native  release apk . however if i run ./gradlew ensembleRelease i get this issue. I try to them by deleting the cache folder first but this don't work. secondly i clean the projet and rebuild by running ./gradlew clean and /.gradlew build again this don't work.  sincerely i am confused